# Upsampling 3D point cloud using PCL

Tags: 3d, point-cloud-library

I have a sparse point cloud of a 3D model. I need to populate the point cloud. In other words, I need to upsample the point cloud for surface reconstruction of the 3D point cloud.

I followed [this](http://www.pointclouds.org/assets/icra2012/surface.pdf) link, but could not understand the method.

Is there an easy way to do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Page 25 to 28 show very nice how to do it in the MLS way. What is it that you don't understand. Did you try to implement and test it?

Answer (score 4):

An alternative resource with some simpler code using the Point Cloud Library is available at the following link:
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/resampling.php

I would suggest starting there. Note that the code just calls an implementation of MLS in the Point Cloud Library. It will be up to you to play with parameters and investigate the code if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. It seems concise. But the given code is for generating normals. After that, how do I get the resampled mesh ?

Comment: I think that `mls.process (mls_points)` puts the resampled mesh into `mls_points`. Haven't looked at the code closely, but I know that `pcl::PointNormal` is a datastructure that has point coordinates as well as normals. Please feel free to correct me..